# Subsite access setting is not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have one Global sitecolection and 5 subsites.I have created 3 groups in global site and I stop inheriting access in My **Subsite1** And created a new **Contributor** Group and added Once User into that Group.Then i try to Login to The Subsite.I got a error

Error: Access Denied
Current User

You are currently signed in as:  asha

Sign in as a different user

I want to create a user with only access ***Subsite1*** ***(Without Global site access-After login it should redirect to home page of subsite)***.How can i achive this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Similar issue asked and solved here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5895/how-to-enable-access-to-subsite-only-to-certain-users-or-groups

Answer (score 0):

A user can login and see a site or list page, he should have View Pages, View Application Pages, Open atomic permission at least, so you can check permission of the login user on Subste1, verify whether he has enough permission to access pages.